# Get data using token auth, and Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, get

My co-worker hand me this code `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://www.example.com/api/transactables?page=1&per_page=1"`. I don't have an idea how to use this until @Rory helped me, but I'm receiving 404 error:

[image]

I used this code from @Rory,
but I'm receiving 404 error, what am I missing?

```js
   $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://www.example.com.au/api/transactables',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        data: {
            page: 1,
            per_page:10
        },
        success: function (){
            console.log('success!');
        },
        error : function (data) {
            console.log('error loading data');
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't think your token is the problem. The issue is that the server you're calling doesn't support CORS requests (i.e. cross-domain requests initiated in a browser environment via ajax). Unless you control the server and can change this, there's not a lot you can do about it. Instead you'd have to use ajax to call your own server, and then use cURL (or whatever, depending on your server language) to launch the request to the remove server, and pass on the response to your ajax request. Effectively, it's using your server as a type of proxy to get around the CORS restrictions.

Comment: thanks @ADyson I tried to run it in console of my domain and it worked!